# mySQL SELECT WHERE CASE

Tags: mysql, select, case, where-clause

I want to make a simple select from a table based on a conditional where clause.

I do like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (SOMETHING TEXT, NAME TEXT, LANG INT(2));

INSERT INTO TEST (SOMETHING, NAME, LANG) VALUES ('123','US',1);
INSERT INTO TEST (SOMETHING, NAME, LANG) VALUES ('234','US',2);
INSERT INTO TEST (SOMETHING, NAME, LANG) VALUES ('345','EU',2);
```

I want to select the NAME in LANG=1 if available otherwise in LANG=2.

I am doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE CASE
WHEN LANG=1 THEN LANG=1
ELSE LANG=2
END
```

I get this:

```
123 US 1
234 US 2
345 EU 2
```

But want this:

```
123 US 1
345 EU 2
```

Should I use a GROUP HAVING or how?

Most appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
select t.*
from test t
where not exists (
  select 1 from test 
  where something <> t.something and name = t.name and lang = 1 
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eHF97s1R9Qqxc5CxNr6BuW/0).
Results:

```
| SOMETHING | NAME | LANG |
| --------- | ---- | ---- |
| 123       | US   | 1    |
| 345       | EU   | 2    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to self-join your table to a list of the minimum `LANG` values by `NAME`, then you can select the `SOMETHING` value associated with that `LANG` value:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TEST T1
JOIN (SELECT NAME, MIN(LANG) AS LANG
      FROM TEST
      GROUP BY NAME) T2 ON T2.NAME = T1.NAME AND T2.LANG = T1.LANG
```

This will return the minimum `LANG` value for each `NAME`, so if a value of 1 exists it will return that, otherwise it will return 2.

Output:

```
SOMETHING   NAME    LANG
345         EU      2
123         US      1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sWJ6uUaGugep9Nc1T5Lhx3/1)

Comment: You are correct, but my example was too simplified. I have updated it. Sorry for your inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

We can handle this using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT SOMETHING, NAME, LANG
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY LANG) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This is probably the most performant way to handle your problem in MySQL, assuming you are using MySQL8+.